# jQuery returns short hand CSS for style attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is it that jQuery returns short hand CSS when I try the following:

```
alert($('#t1').attr('style'));
```

On this html:

```
<div id="t1" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 10px; border-color: red; height: 100px; width: 100px;">Hello</div>
```

It returns:

```
border: 10px solid red; height: 100px; width: 100px;
```

This happens in firefox. Not in chrome.

How can I get the contents of the style attribute exactly as it appears?

Here is a [complete test](http://jsfiddle.net/5UJwF/).

Comment: It's up to the browser how it returns that information. I doubt jQuery tries to parse/interpret the data.

Comment: This may be browser dependent. In Chrome, I got the full style.

Comment: It might be better to state what you plan to do with the style data after you retrieve it.  What is the purpose? Perhaps we can assist.

Comment: FYI: I'm getting the style as you declared ("border-style: solid; border-width: 10px; border-color: red; height: 100px; width: 100px;") in Firefox 7.0.1

Comment: I'm getting the style as you declared ("border-style: solid; border-width: 10px; border-color: red; height: 100px; width: 100px;") in Firefox 7.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for clarification purposes, the conclusion is what has been suggested already - this is a browser interpretation and not a jQuery interpretation. So I've upgraded to FF 7.0 and it seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do?  Hard to see what you want.

That said, what happens if you use pure js, something like

```
(function getStyles(){
    var styles = document.getElementById("t1").getAttribute("style");
    alert(styles);
})();
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/5UJwF/2/